A detail about $L^p$ function approximation
I know polynomial functions are dense in compact support set function space, which is dense in $L^p$ space. But I want to ask a detail in the proof of a property:

Property. Assuming $f\in L^p([0,1]),1\le p\le \infty$ satisfying $\int_0^1f(x)p(x)dx=0$ for any polynomial $p(x)$. Then $f=0$ almost everywhere.

We can find a polynomial sequence $\{p_n\}$ to make approximation, let $\|f-p_n\|_p\to0$. And we have $\|p_n^2\|_p\le\|(f-p_n)p_n\|_p+\|fp_n\|_p$. If I have $\|fp_n\|_p=0$, it will be reduced. But I only have $\|fp_n\|_1=0$, how can I complete it? And how to use $\|f-p_n\|_p\to0$ to estimate $\|(f-p_n)p_n\|_p$? I cannot use Holder inequality here.

The property implies $\int fg =0$ for all continuous $g$. Now apply fundamental lemma of calculus of variations.

@oel that is not correct, because $f$ can take negative and positive values. For example $\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x )dx = 0$.

@jd27 yes, you're right

@daw, maybe $f$ isn't continuous? How can I use fundamental lemma of calculus of variations?

@daw, can I just use some method of inequality and estimates?

the fundamental theorem is true for $f$ just being locally integrable.

We have $L^p(0,1)\subset L^1(0,1).$ Hence it suffices to get the conclusion for $p=1.$

As $L^p(0,1)\subset L^1(0,1),$ it suffices to restrict to $L^1(0,1).$ By the  MacLaurin formula the function $e^{-x^2}$ is the uniform limit of the polynomials ( on every bounded interval. Therefore for $\delta>0$ we get $$f_\delta(x):={1\over \sqrt{\pi}\delta} \int\limits_0^1 f(y)e^{-(x-y)^2/\delta^2}\,dy=0$$ It can be shown that $$\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\|f_\delta-f\|_1=0$$ as the family $\{f_\delta \}_\delta$ forms an approximation identity (see Thm 1.5.3, page 41). Hence $f=0.$

Hence $f=0$ almost every where, you mean.

@Medo I mean $|f|_1=0,$  i.e. $f=0$  almost everywhere.

To obtain the second equality, you applied the first equality to each member of the family ${x\mapsto \delta^{-1} e^{|x-y|/\delta}}_{y\in [0,1],\delta>0}$ ?

@Medo Yes, as each member is a continuous function of the variable $y.$

....a continuous function of $x$ in my notation in the comment. But I get it.

@Medo The symbols $x$ and $\delta>0$ are parameters, while $y$ is a variable.

Provided $1\le p<\infty$, I would go about this a bit differently : for any $0\le a\le 1$, denote by $\chi_a$ the indicator of the interval $[0,a]$ :
$$\chi_a(x) :=\begin{cases}&\!\!\!\! 1\ \text{ if } x\in[0,a], \\&\!\!\!\! 0\  \text{ otherwise }\end{cases} $$
Now, assuming $p>1$ (your proof already takes care of the case $p=1$), let $q$ be such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$. Clearly $\chi_a$ is in $L^q$ so we can find a sequence of polynomials $p_n(a)$ such that $\|\chi_a-p_n(a)\|_q\to 0$. Hence for all $a$,
$$\begin{align}\left|\int_0^1 f\chi_a\right| &\le \left|\int_0^1 f(\chi_a-p_n(a))\right| + \left|\int_0^1 fp_n(a)\right|\\
&\le \|f\|_p\cdot\|\chi_a-p_n(a)\|_q + 0\\
&\to 0\ \text{ as } n\to\infty.\end{align}$$
Where we've used Hölder's inequality and the given property of $f$. Hence we have shown that
$$\int_0^a f(x)\ dx = 0\ \ \text{ for all } a\in[0,1]. \tag 1$$
It is a standard result that an integrable function which satisfies $(1)$ must be zero almost everywhere on $[0,1]$, as is shown here, and so the proof is complete.

Sorry, I didn't make it clear before. I just said that if p=1, $|fp_n|_p$ can become 0, but I don't know how to estimate that $|(f-p_n)p_n|_p$.

@TaD I see. Well actually looking at it again, I strongly suspect that your attempt can't work because you're estimating the $L^{\color{red}{2p}}$ norm of $p_n$, while you only have information about its $L^{\color{red}{p}}$ behaviour, so in some sense you're not the "right" information to solve the problem (of course, I could be wrong about this).

Here's a fun argument that works when $p\notin\{1,\infty\}$.
Suppose that $p\notin\{1,\infty\}$. Letting $q$ be such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ we then have that $L^p([0,1])\cong L^q([0,1])'$, where the identification for our $f$ is given by the linear functional $\ell_f\in L^q([0,1])'$ defined by
$$\ell_f(g)=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
Our condition is that $\ell_f(p)=0$ for all polynomials $p$. By Weierstrass' approximation, for each continuous function $g$ we can find a sequence $\{p_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ with $p_j\to g$ uniformly as $j\to\infty$. As uniform convergence implies $L^q$-convergence, it follows that
$$\ell_f(g)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\ell_f(p_j)=0.$$
Thus $\ell_f(g)=0$ for all continuous $g$. But now as $C([0,1])$ is dense in $L^q([0,1])$ we can for every $g\in L^q([0,1])$ find a sequence $\{g_j\}_{j\in\mathbb N}$ of continuous functions converging to $g$ in $L^q$. It follows that
$$\ell_f(g)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\ell_f(g_j)=0.$$
Thus $\ell_f(g)=0$ for all $g\in L^q([0,1])$, and so $\ell_f=0$. As the map $f\mapsto\ell_f$ was an isomorphism it follows that $f=0$.
